# How to effectively do a color mapping?

Tags: python, image-processing, color-mapping

Given an image I'd like to map each pixel color to a different color. Currently, I'm taking each pixel and comparing against some color ranges, and if the pixel color lays inside that given range, I switch the color.

```
def generate(picture, colors):
    ranges = [127, 254, 381, 509, 636, 766]
    w, h = picture.size

    for i in range(w):
        for j in range(h):
            r, g, b = picture.getpixel((i, j))
            current_color = r + g + b
            for k in range(len(ranges)):
                if current_color < ranges[k]:
                    best_color = colors[k]
                    picture.putpixel((i, j), best_color)
                    break

    return picture

picture = Image.open("images\\image.jpg")
colors = [(0,0,0), (0,0,128), (0,0,255), (77,77,255), (153,153,255), (255,255,255)]
picture = generate(picture,colors)
picture.show()
```

It seems to be working and creating a good image, but is there a way to make it look even closer to the original? Perhaps by changing the range intervals to not be uniform?

Comment: What do you mean by “enhance it even more”? Please be specific about your question. If you want to ask general advice on how to improve your code, you should ask over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for [Color quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization).

Comment: How do I define my own colors in Color quantization?